# how to know the path of file in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i want to connect database to iphone sdk but it is taking the default path inside the system folders but not in the app bundle ?how can i change the file path from that system directory to file in my app bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should retrive your app's document folder path :

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```